# python numpy array iterate on a single axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have seen a few questions similar to mine, but i couldn't find one that suits me.
I want to iterate over one single axis in my array, and without using 2 for loops to make it faster.

First, I open a bunch of pictures and I append them togheter (converting to np array)

after I get an array of array like these:

```
ffImageArr[0]
array([[  45.49061198,  172.49061198,  174.49061198, ...,   30.49061198,
         -71.50938802,  -69.50938802],
       [  60.49061198,  169.49061198,  183.49061198, ...,    0.49061198,
         -83.50938802,  -66.50938802],
       [  55.49061198,  133.49061198,  135.49061198, ...,  -43.50938802,
        -130.50938802,  -99.50938802],
       ..., 
       [ 118.49061198,  203.49061198,  195.49061198, ...,  182.49061198,
          97.49061198,  132.49061198],
       [ 108.49061198,  238.49061198,  197.49061198, ...,  121.49061198,
          99.49061198,  133.49061198],
       [ 118.49061198,  232.49061198,  196.49061198, ...,  130.49061198,
         123.49061198,  145.49061198]])

ffImageArr[1]
array([[  43.59677409,  172.59677409,  173.59677409, ...,   29.59677409,
         -73.40322591,  -71.40322591],
       [  60.59677409,  167.59677409,  182.59677409, ...,    0.59677409,
         -86.40322591,  -64.40322591],
       [  55.59677409,  133.59677409,  134.59677409, ...,  -46.40322591,
        -131.40322591, -102.40322591],
       ..., 
       [ 119.59677409,  201.59677409,  194.59677409, ...,  180.59677409,
          98.59677409,  131.59677409],
       [ 109.59677409,  238.59677409,  197.59677409, ...,  119.59677409,
          98.59677409,  134.59677409],
       [ 117.59677409,  231.59677409,  197.59677409, ...,  129.59677409,
         122.59677409,  144.59677409]])

ffImageArr[2]
array([[  42.16040365,  174.16040365,  177.16040365, ...,   28.16040365,
         -75.83959635,  -74.83959635],
       [  59.16040365,  168.16040365,  183.16040365, ...,   -1.83959635,
         -87.83959635,  -66.83959635],
       [  54.16040365,  133.16040365,  135.16040365, ...,  -47.83959635,
        -133.83959635, -103.83959635],
       ..., 
       [ 119.16040365,  203.16040365,  196.16040365, ...,  182.16040365,
          98.16040365,  132.16040365],
       [ 108.16040365,  240.16040365,  199.16040365, ...,  121.16040365,
          98.16040365,  132.16040365],
       [ 116.16040365,  232.16040365,  196.16040365, ...,  129.16040365,
         122.16040365,  143.16040365]])

ffImageArr[3]
array([[  43.89271484,  174.89271484,  175.89271484, ...,   28.89271484,
         -78.10728516,  -75.10728516],
       [  59.89271484,  169.89271484,  183.89271484, ...,   -2.10728516,
         -89.10728516,  -67.10728516],
       [  54.89271484,  132.89271484,  135.89271484, ...,  -50.10728516,
        -137.10728516, -105.10728516],
       ..., 
       [ 118.89271484,  204.89271484,  195.89271484, ...,  181.89271484,
          98.89271484,  131.89271484],
       [ 108.89271484,  240.89271484,  199.89271484, ...,  121.89271484,
          98.89271484,  134.89271484],
       [ 118.89271484,  234.89271484,  199.89271484, ...,  128.89271484,
         123.89271484,  145.89271484]])
```

My goal is to retrieve an array with the n element of each of these arrays, it's and array of array as fast as possible.

like `array =[45.49061198,43.59677409,42.16040365...]`

I tried

```
for i in range(ffImageArr.shape[0]):
    print ffImageArr[i,:,:]
```

but weirdly, `[i,:,:]` gives the same thing as `[:,i:]`

Thanks for the help and explanation!

edit :
code that I wrote in the meantime, I will try to use polyfit directly as suggested :

```
for k in range (ffImageArr.shape[1]):
   for i in range(ffImageArr.shape[2]):
 fffunc = []
 for j in range(ffImageArr.shape[0]): 
    fffunc.append(ffImageArr[j,k,i])
 fffunc = np.array(fffunc)
 a = np.polyfit(tempArr,fffunc,1)
 firstOrder0.append(a[1])
 firstOrder1.append(a[0])
 b = np.polyfit(tempArr,fffunc,2)   
 secondOrder0.append(b[2])
 secondOrder1.append(b[1])  
 secondOrder2.append(b[1])
 c = np.polyfit(tempArr,fffunc,3)   
 thirdOrder0.append(c[3])
 thirdOrder1.append(c[2])   
 thirdOrder2.append(c[1])
 thirdOrder3.append(c[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are grayscale images with only one band/channel and not RGB, i.e. of shape (N, D) and not (N, D, 3), then you can use list comprehension.

```py
# Generate 5 single-band images of size 8x8
ims = np.random.randn(5, 8, 8)

# Coordinates of the nth value
x = 1
y = 1

arr = [im[n, n] for im in ims]
```